# Determine if given text is C code

Tags: c, linux-kernel, smtp, firewall

I am trying to build a Linux Kernel level firewall, and I need to create a DLP (Data loss prevention) layer in it.

I need to determine if a give email (sent over SMTP) is C code or plain text.
The code doesn't have to be a complete program, so I won't be able to use the compiler for this task.

For example, the following code should be caught:

```
if (variable == true) { printf("The statement is true\n"); }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Very difficult, and depends on what range of variations you can receive.  So why don't you specify what kind of input you can get!

Comment: it should be plain text, or partial C code... That is the specification that I received...

Comment: That's a stupid/impossible spec, because then `f (variable == true) { printf("The` is also partial C code.  Do you see what I mean?!

Comment: lol... In partial C code, the meaning is complete commands, but not necessarily a complete program/function... I thought I might write a Lexer, but that sounds like overkill

Comment: you probably mean *complete statements* - in which case you should be able to use the compiler, or at least the lexer/parser ?

Comment: Referring to the [C grammar](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~mckeeman/cs48/references/c.html) what exactly do you mean with 'commands'?

Comment: Extract it and compile it.

Comment: @meaning-matters probably a complete statement/expression

Comment: @stijn how would I use the C lexer?

Comment: There is no *the* C lexer.. lots of options, here's just one: https://github.com/eliben/pycparser. All in all, if you're in for creating a working DLP and not a usability nightmare you're going to have to do some serious learning and gain understanding of all concepts involved.

Comment: After `typedef int I;` the following is a valid declaration in c: `I see;`. Are you prepared to filter this?

Comment: @EOF Well, your example is impossible to filter out, so what DLP's usually do is allow false positives, but false negatives should not happen...

Comment: My point is that by filtering for fragments, you don't have a context-free grammar to work with. You can't win.

Comment: @EOF I agree, but I could block all leaks if I allow false positives, but I would like to keep those to a minimum...

Comment: If the code you look for has any significant amount of preprocessor work, you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: Allowing false positives will pi$$ off users very likely, unless they are kept to a minimum. Nevertheless: What is the usage adding such to the kernel and not user-space, e.g. to the mailer? I strongly support @stijn: first learn the underlying ideas and concepts.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a 'statement', I would suggest to get a (Lex/Yacc) C parser.  Put the parser in the 'expecting-statement state' and run it.  If you don't get errors, you know it's valid.

Depending on what parser you get, you may have to strip away a lot of code; things like symbol table lookup/check when a variable is encountered, ...  But I wouldn't be surprized if there are bare-bones implementations that are (almost) ready for you to use.

You could also download a pure C Lex and Yacc specifications and write some code around it to make it work; it's not difficult.  But it does require a good amount of effort to get your head around it.

Comment: I already had the dubious pleasure of creating a lexer/parser as part of a compiler, and I was hoping for a different way, but it seems there is no good way around it... Thanks!

Comment: The only other direction I can imagine is textual/word analyses, like they do with natural language which then results in probabilities. But that would hardly (if not at all) work for a programming language, and this kind of methods would require a good sized input data set.

Answer (score 0):

For a more generic **Code vs Text** classification you could also try any of the following:

- train a Markov Model (e.g. use CRM114 - http://crm114.sourceforge.net/)
- letter trigram analysis
- simple letter frequency analysis (high percentage of parenthesis, curly braces, operator characters could indicate code)